# python memory error when read iostream into a big string

Tags: string, python-3.x, split

I have the following code that reads iostream into a string and do some manipulations on the string:

```
# this where memory error happened
data_str = io.StringIO(iostream.getvalue().decode('utf-8')).read()
# split the data string into a list of lines, breaking at line boundaries.
split_lines = data_str.splitlines()

if name == 'a':
    split_lines.insert(0, 'a_ID,a_VALUE')

elif name == 'b':
    split_lines.insert(0, 'b_ID,b_VALUE')

data_new_headers_str = '\n'.join(split_lines)

data_new_headers_io_str = io.StringIO(data_new_headers_str)
```

the idea is to insert a header string into the 1st position of the split string list, i.e. `split_lines`, which is acquired by first read an iostring and split it into a list of strings.

I got `MemoryError` when running `data_str = io.StringIO(iostream.getvalue().decode('utf-8')).read()`, I am wondering how to fix this issue or a better way to do this work in terms of memory efficiency.

Comment: How big is the string actually?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson according to `sys.getsizeof(iostream)`, it is 88, `iostream` is of `BytesIO` object

Comment: That is the size of the stream object itself, but the issue is with how much is read from it. Does it read from a disk file?

Comment: @ArndtJonasson yes, it is read from the hard drive, decompressed and unencrypted

Comment: I suggest reading one line at a time from it, not the whole thing at once. There is probably a way to read uncompressed lines from the compressed file - whether the encryption allows this depends on the encryption, I'd guess.

Comment: @ArndtJonasson do you know how to concatenate two `BytesIO` objects? I am thinking about making the header as `BytesIO` and concatenate it with `iostream`